# Application Insights error "Rate limit is exceeded" when executing event request using API

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to call Application insights API using pageviews Event and i get this error message

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Rate limit is exceeded",
    "code": "ThrottledError",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "ThrottledError",
      "message": "Rate limit of 0 per day is exceeded.",
      "limitValue": 0,
      "moreInfo": "https://aka.ms/api-limits"
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone help me fix this ?

Comment: could you access the api before or is it the first attempt?

Comment: yes I can call it using merics but i cant using events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this issue if you are on the old pricing model, and you don't if you are on the new pricing model.

Unless you created a brand new Application Insights instance very recently, you are probably are on the old pricing model. Easiest way to tell is if you see "Features + pricing" in your Application Insights, you are on the new model.

[image: Difference between models]

There is no difference between changing the pricing plan (between free/standard/premium), the throttle is still there.

If you want to move to the new pricing model, Microsoft offer two options:

> If you’re willing to wait until February 1st, 2017, we will handle the transition automatically for you, and this will be the best option for most customers. Under this approach, we will transition your application to Application Insights Basic in most cases. (Applications using continuous export or the Connector for OMS Log Analytics will be transitioned to Application Insights Enterprise.)
>
> However, if you prefer to use one of the new pricing options immediately, you can also do this. It involves choosing to stop billing for your existing plan (Standard or Premium), then creating a new Application Insights resource within the Azure portal, choosing the pricing option you prefer, and then updating the Instrumentation Key within your application. One downside of doing this is that you will lose the continuity of reporting because you will have the old Instrumentation Key for your application under the Preview plan, and a new Instrumentation Key for your application under the new pricing model.

This can be found as the last FAQ item on the [Application Insights pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/application-insights/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i looked into azure portal and found that i was on old pricing model when i create new application insights it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

according to the link in the result you got back:

https://aka.ms/api-limits

it depends on what the response code was, and what other headers you get back:

> If requests are being made at a rate higher than this, then these requests will receive a status code 429 (Too Many Requests) along with the header Retry-After: 60 which indicates the number of seconds until requests to this application are likely to be accepted.
>
> In the event that the Application Insights service is under high load or is down for maintenance, a status code 503 (Service Unavailable) will be returned, and in some cases a Retry-After header may be returned.

Comment: after checking with the team that owns this service they immediately knew what it was, so i came to update my answer and found that FreeRangeEggs already added that answer. :)

Comment: Thanks John for help:)